# eBay FindingAPI - findItemsByProduct returns 'Invalid product ID value' error for EBAY-US site

Tags: php, ebay-api

I'm trying to integrate eBay API in my project.
I use ZendFramework and there is library for eBay FindingAPI, but it doesn't work for method `findItemsByProduct`.

For understanding problem I wrote my small class:

```
<?php
class MyProject_Model_Ebay 
{
    const FINDING_API_URL = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?';

    private $appId;

    public function __construct($appId)
    {
        $this->appId = $appId;
    }

    public function findByProduct($id, $type = 'UPC')
    {
        $params = array(
            'productId.@type' => $type,
            'productId' => $id,
        );

        return $this->doApiRequest('findItemsByProduct', $params);
    }

    public function findByKeywords($keywords)
    {
        $params = array(
            'keywords' => $keywords,
        );

        return $this->doApiRequest('findItemsByKeywords', $params);
    }


    private function doApiRequest($operationName, $payload)
    {

        $global = array(
            'OPERATION-NAME' => $operationName,
            'SECURITY-APPNAME' => $this->appId,
            'GLOBAL-ID' => 'EBAY-US',
            'SERVICE-VERSION' => '1.0.0',
            'MESSAGE-ENCODING' => 'UTF-8',
            'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' => 'JSON',
        );

        $ret = file_get_contents(
            self::FINDING_API_URL . http_build_query($global) . '&REST-PAYLOAD&' . http_build_query($payload)
        );

        return $ret;
    }

}
```

Method `findItemsByKeywords` works OK, but `findItemsByProduct` still returns error

> Invalid product ID value.

I tried different variants of passing value, but it doesn't work :( Current version of passing value I saw here: [how to use python xml.etree.ElementTree to parse eBay API response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110440/how-to-use-python-xml-etree-elementtree-to-parse-ebay-api-response)

Usage:

```
<?php
$eBay = new MyProject_Model_Ebay(
    'My-app-id'
);

$eBay->findByProduct('4719331316129');
```

Response:

```
{"findItemsByProductResponse":[{"ack":["Failure"],"errorMessage":[{"error":[{"errorId":["41"],"domain":["Marketplace"],"severity":["Error"],"category":["Request"],"message":["Invalid product ID value."],"subdomain":["Search"],"parameter":["4719331316129"]}]}],"version":["1.11.1"],"timestamp":["2012-03-14T06:41:42.600Z"]}]}
```

Important!
If i change GLOBAL-ID on EBAY-DE, for example, everything is OK! What's wrong with EBAY-US?!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you had passed incorrect product ID (itemID instead of ProductID). 
$eBay->findByProduct('4719331316129'); - 13 digits, when normally ProductId has 8-9 digits
Compare:

```
<item>
  <itemId>230823026330</itemId>
  <title>Apple iPhone 3G - 8GB - Black (AT&amp;T) Smartphone #26459</title>
  <globalId>EBAY-US</globalId>
  <primaryCategory>
    <categoryId>9355</categoryId>
    <categoryName>Cell Phones &amp; Smartphones</categoryName>
  </primaryCategory>
  <galleryURL>http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/pict/2308230263304040_1.jpg</galleryURL>
  <viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iPhone-3G-8GB-Black-AT-T-Smartphone-26459-/230823026330?pt=Cell_Phones</viewItemURL>
  <productId type="ReferenceID">101892398</productId>
```

Comment: Actually, it is too late to make a comment on this topic..
I am a bit confusing the above answer. The question is trying to look up the products, using "UPC" code. UPC code is 12 digits. So, the question actually gave the wrong digits because it gave "13" digits. But, the above answer just use Reference ID.
Actually, I am having the same issue where Reference ID is working. But, giving UPC code cause "Invalid product ID value". Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @user2533493 you are right, i didn't notice this moment (EAN-13 — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code — is superset for UPC and has 13 digits. UPC could be converted to EAN-13, but not vice versa). I do not remember how I solved this problem in my app.

Comment: @DmitryMerkushin Please share the details on how you solved this problem, when you get your hands on the app. I am having the same problem right now. Both UPC/EAN are not working(says "Invalid product ID value"), but Reference ID is working. I think it should be EAN though as it is a 13 digit number. I have tried this for both EBAY-US & EBAY-DE as GLOBAL-ID. FWIW, the barcode I tried is 0016000275270

Comment: @DmitryMerkushin I have asked this as a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333904/ebay-api-call-not-working-for-upc-ean

Answer (score 0):

The Id you are sending is been treated as the UPC of a product.

The findItemsByProduct requires
 productId

type is must be specified while passing product id.
Type can include ISBN, UPC, EAN, or ReferenceID (ePID).

In your case, the ID you are passing is considered as the UPC number. So confirm whether the UPC is correct for that product.